# Layout weight not changing in xml

Tags: java, android

I have a XML code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"

    >
    <fragment
        android:name="com.powergroup.split.view.powerListFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/powerlist_fragment"
      android:layout_weight="45"

        >
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:name="com.powergroup.split.view.powerViewerFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/powerview_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="55"
       >
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

but if I change the value of layout_weight it doesnt take any effect and always shows the same, how can i figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set fragments' **layout_width** to **0dp** in order for weight to kick-in. See below:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Comment: I did, but no change is happening

Comment: did you set it to both fragments?

Answer (score 0):

*layout_weight* is appliable only to "unused" pixel distribution. All of your fragments have fill_parent as width. So, there are no "unused" pixels in this case. Try to set layout_width="0dip".